# What to use as key in dictionary for users connecting to a server?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

If I were to have the TcpClient as the value what would a good value for the key be? IP address? Static counter variable incremented for each connection?

Is there not a better way to find the IP address of a tcp client rather than this?

`client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()`

What do most people usually use?

Comment: With TCP connections, isn't it customary to use IP + Port to identify clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify a client see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariya/archive/2006/06/19/636437.aspx .

As key for the Dictionary I would use

```
string MyDictKey = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString()  + ":" + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.Port.ToString();
```

BTW: if your server is multi-threaded I would strongly recommend using a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).

Comment: Ah, yes, the port number too. I knew I was forgetting something. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome - please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...